# Pygame: one version of image.load works with my image, but the other version will not. I must be missing somthing obvious

Tags: pygame

Most of the examples of pygame use the version of pygame.image.load() that accepts a filename. That's cool and all, but sometimes it simply isn't enough, so I'm trying to get the version that accepts a fileobject and namehint to work.

So here's the problem. This works:

```
def loadSplashImgDirect(filename):
    return  pygame.image.load(filename))
```

This raises "pygame.error: Unsupported image format"

```
def loadSplashImgOpen():
    aFile = open(filename, 'r')
    return pygame.image.load(aFile,filename)
```

As near as I can tell, these functions should be doing exactly the same thing. Or am I reading the documentation wrong?

Comment: What is the goal? Open a image from a handle not the name? why? -- Maybe you are looking for the fromstring and from buffer load methods? http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/index.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are reading the image from a file-like object, you have to ensure that the file's current position is at the begining, a.k.a. at offset `0`.

For example:

```
f = open(filename)
content = f.read()
pygame.image.load(f, filename)
```

won't work, since the file object points to the end of the file when you call `image.load`.

You can use `seek` to set the file's current position to the begining, hence

```
f = open(filename)
content = f.read()
f.seek(0)
pygame.image.load(f, filename)
```

works as expected.

Comment: Thanks! This works, but it should be noted that you need to open the file with 'rb' as the second arg-'r' because you're only reading from it, and 'b' prevents it from trying to read it as unicode (and failing hard.)

Comment: @EamonnM.R. That's true for all operating systems that treat binary and text files differently (a.k.a. Windows). You don't have to use `rb` on Linux, but you should for portability.